# Eslint with Vue3 reverts itself on save

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I'm using Eslint with Vue3. `.ts` files work just fine and the style part of a Vue file does as well. The problem is with indentation on the props of a component on the `template` part and in full on the `script` part.

As soon as I save a file, it formats to the wanted indentation but immediately reverts the changes to no indentation whatsoever.

Example of a script portion:

How it is initially:

```
type MessagesType = {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  type?: string;
};
```

How is should be:

```
  type MessagesType = {
    title: string;
    message: string;
    type?: string;
  };
```

When I hit save it goes to how it should be but immediately gets reverted to how it was initially. Even if the second one is the initial way it reverts to the first one.

.eslintrc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    commonjs: true,
    jest: true,
    es2022: true,
  },

  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import'],

  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],

  rules: {
    // global rules:
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'warn',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'warn',
    'no-async-promise-executor': 'warn',
    'no-trailing-spaces': 'warn',
    'no-template-curly-in-string': 'warn',
    'no-multi-spaces': 'warn',


    // typescript rules (https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/):
    '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions': ['warn', 'type'],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/prefer-for-of': 'warn',
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'warn',

    'semi': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/semi': 'warn',

    'comma-dangle': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/comma-dangle': ['warn', 'always-multiline'],

    'indent': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/indent': ['warn', 2],

    'object-curly-spacing': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/object-curly-spacing': ['error', 'always'],

    'quotes': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/quotes': ['warn', 'single'],

    'comma-spacing': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/comma-spacing': 'warn',

    'block-spacing': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/block-spacing': 'warn',

    'func-call-spacing': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/func-call-spacing': 'warn',

    'key-spacing': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/key-spacing': 'warn',

    'keyword-spacing': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/keyword-spacing': 'warn',

    'space-before-blocks': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/space-before-blocks': 'warn',

    'space-before-function-paren': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/space-before-function-paren': ['warn', {
      'anonymous': 'always',
      'named': 'never',
      'asyncArrow': 'always',
    }],

    'space-infix-ops': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/space-infix-ops': 'warn',

    'no-extra-semi': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-extra-semi': 'warn',

    'no-unused-expressions': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions': 'warn',

    '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports': ['warn', {
      prefer: 'type-imports',
      disallowTypeAnnotations: true,
      fixStyle: 'inline-type-imports',
    }],


    // Vue specific rules (https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/):
    'vue/attribute-hyphenation': 'off',
    'vue/v-on-event-hyphenation': 'off',
    'vue/script-indent': ['warn', 2, { 'baseIndent': 1 }],
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': ['warn', {
      'singleline': {
        'max': 4,
      },
      'multiline': {
        'max': 1,
      },
    }],
    'vue/no-unused-components': 'warn',
    'vue/no-unused-vars': 'warn',
    'vue/component-name-in-template-casing': 'warn',
    'vue/component-options-name-casing': 'warn',
    'vue/custom-event-name-casing': 'warn',
    'vue/define-macros-order': 'warn',
    'vue/define-props-declaration': ['error', 'runtime'],
    'vue/no-unused-refs': 'warn',
    'vue/padding-line-between-blocks': 'warn',
    'vue/prefer-prop-type-boolean-first': 'warn',


    // import rules (https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import):
    'import/no-unresolved': 'warn',
    'import/order': ['warn',
      {
        'groups': [
          ['builtin', 'external'],
          'internal',
          ['sibling', 'parent', 'index'],
          // 'type',
        ],
        'newlines-between': 'always',
        'warnOnUnassignedImports': true,
      },
    ],
    'import/consistent-type-specifier-style': ['warn', 'prefer-inline'],
    'import/no-duplicates': ['warn', { 'prefer-inline': true }],
  },

  settings: {
    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      'typescript': {
        'alwaysTryTypes': true,
      },
    },
  },

  overrides: [
    {
      // disable original/ts indent rule for .vue files, to allow vue/script-indent handle them (otherwise both will)
      files: ['*.vue'],
      rules: {
        'indent': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/indent': 'off',
      },
    },

    {
      files: [
        '*.spec.{j,t}s',
      ],
      rules: {
        'no-unused-expressions': 'off',
      },
    },
    {
      files: [
        '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)',
        '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)',
      ],
      env: {
        jest: true,
      },
    },
  ],

};
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "login",
  "version": "3.3.3",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite --port=8082",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint:production": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.6",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "node": "^16.20.2",
    "pinia": "^2.1.6",
    "quasar": "^2.12.7",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "eslint": "^8.51.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.12",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.5"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint:production"
  ]
}
```

This is quite a pickle and I'm not sure how to tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the following on the VS Code `.code-workspace` file:

```
"[vue]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
},
```

This was conflicting with Eslint.